# Handling response from an ASP.NET web service using Jquery's Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I have this response coming from a ASP.NET web service

```
<string xmlns="http://Walkthrough/XmlWebServices/">
{"approverName":"","emailAddress":"","companyName":"ABC","address":{"streetAddress1":"12 BlahBlah","streetAddress2":"","state":"ON","zipCode":"","country":"SO","phoneNumber":""},"tabledata:"[{"vendorPart":"AAAAA","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"28"},{"vendorPart":"BBBBBBB","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"3"},{"vendorPart":"CCCCCC","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"25"}]}
</string>
```

which is being called with this jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123",
                data: "tnWsGuid=TEST1",
                dataType: "script",
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        alert("sucess")
                    },
                    error: function(e)
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(e));                       
                    }
                    });
            });
```

My first question is this, I was having 403 forbidden issues with this function but omitting the contentType changed that. Then I was getting XML parsing issue and on a whim changing the dataType to script fixed that and gave me a response and I hit the success function. Why did that work?

I also would like to know how I can print out this data, because trying to treat it as json won't work, neither does XML.

In chrome I receive this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123?tnWsGuid=TEST1&_=1366025879568."
```

The part appended to the end of this url is confusing me (after TEST1).
In the console I also get this error in chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Firebug gives me:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
 [Break On This Error]  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://Walkthrough/XmlWebServices/">
    {"approverName":"","emailAddress":"","companyName":"ABC","address":{"streetAddress1":"12 BlahBlah","streetAddress2":"","state":"ON","zipCode":"","country":"SO","phoneNumber":""},"tabledata:"[{"vendorPart":"AAAAA","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"28"},{"vendorPart":"BBBBBBB","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"3"},{"vendorPart":"CCCCCC","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"25"}]}
    </string>
```

So basically now that the dataType is script I get some sort of response but still have no idea how to parse this data. Preferably into a html table.

I hope you can help! Thanks for reading!

Edit:

Here is a link to the header information logged by Firebug [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oxtj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue and successfully have it working on IE returning the dataset (not yet working on Chrome and Firefox due to the asynchronous problem with the two which I hope will be fixed when hosting this page. I added `$.support.cors = true;` right before the ajax function and my new success function properly show's the data like so:

`function(data, status, jqxhr) {
       xmlString = data;

       alert(xmlString);
}`

Answer (score 1):

your need to set datatype to json as the server send a json array.
see the datatype section here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: When I change it to json I get the error from the code (status: 0, readyState: 0, StatusText: error) and this error (in chrome) `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123s. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`